# R: cannot find exported function even after importing entire namespace

Tags: r, package

I'm building a package, `myPackage` that imports from several other packages. The problem is that a function `fun` (it's actually a method) that is exported from another package `otherPackage` cannot be found when run. I did all of the following:

1. `Imports: otherPackage` and `Depends: methods` in `myPackage`'s `DESCRIPTION` file
2. `import(otherPackage)` in `myPackage`'s `NAMESPACE` file
3. Also tried adding `importMethodsFrom(otherPackage,"fun")`

The *only* way I found it to work is if I replace `Imports: otherPackage` with `Depends: otherPackage`, but we all know that it is recommended to import another package's namespace instead of attaching it to the search path. Can someone please explain why Importing it doesn't work?

Specifics: the function in question is `keys` from package `AnnotationDbi` in Bioconductor. The specific error is `Error in .select(x, keys, columns, keytype) : 
  could not find function "keys"`

Thank you.

Comment: You need `Imports: AnnotationDbi` in your description, and `importMethodsFrom(AnnotationDbi, keys)` in your namespace.

Comment: Tried that, no luck. See points 1 and 3 in my edited post.

Comment: It looks like AnnotationDbi actually has several packages listed as depends (including methods).  This might make it so that the only option you have is to use depends yourself.

Comment: I tried to import every package in the depends of AnnotationDbi with no luck either. I'm really confused about why importing all of those namespaces doesn't work.

Comment: @FBC it's not clear what you tried at the same time. I'd recommend creating a minimal reproducible example that illustrates the problem, and post publicly (ideally on github)

Comment: I faced the same problem. My package was running correctly. Then, it started to give error interestingly. My DESCRIPTION file includes "Imports: np(>= 0.50-1)" and my NAMESPACE file includes "importFrom(np,b.star)" (without quotes, of course). When I run b.star(granger.df) in R console, it gave this error: "Error: could not find function "b.star" ".

Comment: In Object Browser in Revolution R, even though I commanded library(causfinder), the (must) imported package np is not shown there! After introducing library(np) in R console, b.star(granger.df) works. We of course want it works without library(np).

Comment: Same issue here when trying to import "sp" ...